# Text Alignment of ListViewItem

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tlistview

In Firemonkey of Delphi 10.4. I want to build a list view where the listview item text appears either left- or right-aligned depending on the list item content.

[image]

I do this as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

  procedure AddItem(No: integer);
  var
    Item: TListViewItem;
  begin
    Item := ListView1.Items.AddItem(No);
    Item.Text := 'Text item No ' + No.ToString;
    Item.Tag := No;
    if No mod 2 = 0 then
      Item.Objects.TextObject.TextAlign := TTextAlign.Leading
    else
      Item.Objects.TextObject.TextAlign := TTextAlign.Trailing;
  end;

var
  c: integer;
begin
  for c := 0 to 9 do
    AddItem(c);
end;
```

However, this does not work on all platforms. But as soon as the ListView changes its size, all ListItems appear flush on the left.  Is there a better way to do this?

As a workaround, I have done the following:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1Resized(Sender: TObject);
var
  c: integer;
begin
  for c := 0 to ListView1.ItemCount - 1  do
    if ListView1.Items[c].Tag mod 2 = 0 then
      ListView1.Items[c].Objects.TextObject.TextAlign := TTextAlign.Leading
    else
      ListView1.Items[c].Objects.TextObject.TextAlign := TTextAlign.Trailing;
end;
```

Comment: I think it's better to fully custom the ListViewItem. You can put a TLayout, TRectangle or TText and do what you want and the result will always be the same on all platefiorm

Comment: Looks like a 2 person chat. Why even using a `TListView` when you only want one column without a header anyway? Wouldn't a `TRichEdit` be a better choice, as it also lets the user select portions of text to copy it to the clipboard?

Comment: Yes, I build a simple chat for testing and demonstrating the upcoming Firestore listener in FB4D OpenSource Library. @Bosshoss: Yes, that would be probably the best solution but it requires probably more code for this control than the entire demo application.@AmigoJack: To use the richedit you'd be a solution but I want a short demonstration to click a message for the edit and delete function. If I want to extend the sample in the future with a profile image of the sender, a TListView or TListBox would be better suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ItemAppearance=ListItem` this problem cannot be solved, because in the internal `ResetView` method the `Item.Objects.TextObject` all properties will written back to `ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects`.

Therefore, `ItemAppearance` must be set to `DynamicAppearance` for this application. Two `TextObjectAppearance` objects must be manually created in the *Structure View* under `ListView.ItemAppearance.Item`, where `Text1` must be set to a `TextAlign=Leading` and `Text2` to `TextAlign=Trailing`.

[image]

After that, only one *Text Object* has to be filled with the text:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

  procedure AddItem(No: integer);
  var
    Item: TListViewItem;
  begin
    Item := ListView1.Items.AddItem(No);
    if No mod 2 = 0 then
      Item.Data['Text1'] := 'Text item No ' + No.ToString
    else
      Item.Data['Text2'] := 'Text item No ' + No.ToString
  end;

var
  c: integer;
begin
  for c := 0 to 9 do
    AddItem(c);
end;
```

Here is the corresponding FMX file:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object ListView1: TListView
    ItemAppearanceClassName = 'TDynamicAppearance'
    ItemEditAppearanceClassName = 'TDynamicAppearance'
    HeaderAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
    FooterAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
    Align = Client
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 480.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
    ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.ObjectsCollection = <
      item
        AppearanceObjectName = 'Text1'
        AppearanceClassName = 'TTextObjectAppearance'
        Appearance.TextAlign = Leading
      end
      item
        AppearanceObjectName = 'Text2'
        AppearanceClassName = 'TTextObjectAppearance'
        Appearance.TextAlign = Trailing
      end>
    ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemEditObjects.ObjectsCollection = <
      item
        AppearanceObjectName = 'Text1'
        AppearanceClassName = 'TTextObjectAppearance'
      end>
  end
end
```